# find() with mongoose on a dynamical path

Tags: mongoose

I would like to find every `group` documents about the `user_id` field in all my `members`array entries:

```
"group": {
  "name": 'group_1',
  "members": [
  {
    "user_id": ObjectId("51153212835b351826000001"),
    "right": 1,
  },{
    "user_id": ObjectId("51153212835b351826000002"),
    "right": 3,
  },
  ]
}

"group": {
  "name": 'group_2',
  "members": [
  {
    "user_id": ObjectId("51153212835b351826000001"),
    "right": 1,
  },{
    "user_id": ObjectId("51153212835b351826000002"),
    "right": 3,
  },
  ]
}
```

I saw the operator `$in` but i am not sure i can use it in this case because i just have one 'user_id' and i need to use it to look for a "dynamical path" `group.members[x].user_id`

Is there a way to do this request dynamically ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed using the `$elementMatch` operator .